# Android Studio 2.2.2 does not run new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a new project and ran it without a single change. 
But the project is not running and the hello world app is throwing 'Transform expection'.

Things I tried:

1. multidex enabled  :- same error
2. Dex options maxheapsize 4g : same error
3. packaging options exclude :- same error

Code:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blood_bank"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
   
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

```html
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No dex files created at C:\Users\arcgis\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\5\slice_9
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 27.813 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: disable instant run and after that try again.

Comment: You save my day @JinalPatel .... Thanks a lot perfect answer

Comment: Hardly perfect if you have to disable a feature. Treat the underlying condition not a symptom. I'd start with `buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"`.

Comment: same error with 25.0.0 Eugen Pechanec

Answer (score 0):

remove this line :

```
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```